# Verificação ao gravar no BD

Tags: php

Então, eu consegui com que meu form gravasse no Banco de Dados as informações digitadas, porém, mesmo se não houver informação digitada, e clicar em gravar, ele grava. Não consegui achar o erro, já que o arquivo de verificação possui as linhas que verificam o campo vazio.

Será que alguém consegue me ajudar a achar o erro!?

O código está abaixo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Guia de Consulta CNS"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>


<?php
$tAut       =$_POST ["tAut"];
$tPrest     =$_POST ["tPrest"];
$tCart      =$_POST ["tCart"];
$cDadm      =$_POST ["cDadm"];
$tNome      =$_POST ["tNome"];
$tNasc      =$_POST ["tNasc"];
$tCnpj      =$_POST ["tCnpj"];
$tNomecont  =$_POST ["tNomecont"];
$tCodcnes   =$_POST ["tCodcnes"];
$tProf      =$_POST ["tProf"];
$tEsp       =$_POST ["tEsp"];
$tConsr     =$_POST ["tConsr"];
$tNcons     =$_POST ["tNcons"];
$tCbos      =$_POST ["tCbos"];
$tDatatm    =$_POST ["tDatatm"];
$tTab       =$_POST ["tTab"];
$tCodp      =$_POST ["tCodp"];
$erro       =0;

//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tAut))
{
  $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Autorização obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tPrest))
{
   $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Número da Guia do Prestador obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

if (empty($tCart))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Número da Carteirinha obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($cDadm))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Data de Admissão obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tNome))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Nome obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tNasc))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Data de Nascimento obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tCnpj))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento do CNPJ obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tNomecont))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Nome do Contratado obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tCodcnes))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Código CNES obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tProf))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento  do Profissional Executante obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tEsp))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Especialidade obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tConsr))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Conselho Regional obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tNcons))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Número do Conselho obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tCbos))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Número do CBOS obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tDatatm))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Data de Atendimento obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tTab))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Tabela  obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tCodp))
{
    $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Código do Procedimento obrigatório!<br>';
}

if (isset($error))
{
    foreach($error as $msg) {
        echo $msg;
    }
}
//Verifica se não houve erro.
if ($erro==0)
{
    $error[] = 'Todos os campos preenchidos corretamente!';
include "insere.php";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você inicializa `$erro = 0;` e depois você verifica se `if ($erro==0)` e em nenhum momento você seta alguma coisa para essa variavel. Então sempre vai inserir.

Answer (score 1):

A variável `$erro`, você apenas criou mas não mudou o valor dela em momento algum. Por esse motivo, ele sempre vai gravar.

Porém, não é necessário utilizar essa variável uma vez que você já define a variável `$error` quando há erro. Logo, basta testar apenas se `$error` está setado, caso contrário (`else`) gravar.

```
if (isset($error)){ // se houve erro
    foreach($error as $msg) {
        echo $msg;
    }
} else { // não houve erro
    $error[] = 'Todos os campos preenchidos corretamente!';
    include "insere.php";
}
```

Comment: Allan, seu trecho me ajudou para mostrar a mensagem de erro quando o campo está nulo. Mas agora mesmo os campos preenchidos e na hora de gravar no banco de dados, aparece a mensagem de que está salvo no banco mas quando eu vou verificar, o banco de dados está em branco. Saberia me dizer porque desse erro?

Comment: Você precisa criar outra pergunta e colocar nela os seus códigos de gravação no banco de dados para seja possível analisar o porque desse erro.

Comment: Me avisa quando criar a outra pergunta que vou dar uma olhada para tentar te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

No inicio do seu código você declara a variavel `erro` como 0;

```
$erro = 0;
```

E no final você verifica se erro é igual a 0;

```
if ($erro==0)...
```

Como `$erro` já foi definido como 0 ele vai cair como verdade `true` na sua verificação.

Para arrumar isso você tem 2 opções.

1. Fazer um incremento em cada verificação de campos vazios, por exemplo.

   ```
   if (empty($tCodp))
   {
      $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Código do Procedimento obrigatório!<br>';
      $erro += 1;
   }
   ```

   Desta maneira a variavel `$erro` vai ser somada de 1 em 1 para cada campo que estiver vazio.
2. Remover a variavel `$erro` do inicio do código e validar usando o `array $error`, por exemplo;

   ```
   if (empty($error))
   {
      $error[] = 'Todos os campos preenchidos corretamente!';
      include "insere.php";
   }
   ```